# Need a macro that searches for values, and if true it selects the row with the value and the row above

Tags: vba, excel

I hope I don't confuse you but here's what I'm trying to do.

Here's an example of what some of the data in the sheet looks like:

#### Excel Screenshot

[image: Excel Screenshot]

Basically I have a criteria of 6 four-digit numbers e.g. (3413, 3414, 3417 etc.) and I need the macro to search for any rows that have a number that begins with any of these numbers, and copy both the row the value is in and the row above to a new sheet. I need the row above because it has the customer's name in it.

In this case the macro would find the value in row 2 and copy both row 2 and row 1.

I can't seem to find anyone that has the same issue as me, can anyone help? Thanks!

Edit - this would likely be my starting code:

```
Sub Test()
For Each Cell In Sheets(1).Range("J:J")
    If Cell.Value = "131125" Then
        matchRow = Cell.Row
        Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Select
        Selection.Copy

        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        ActiveSheet.Rows(matchRow).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: How about posting the VBA code you have tried so far?

Comment: I haven't tried any code because I haven't found any code that does what I want, hence me asking the question.

I have code saved somewhere that can copy the row with the value only, sure. I can show you that.

Comment: A code is not always about finding it, it is much more about writing it!

Comment: I'm ok at editing code but definitely not good enough to write something like this from scratch! Hence me using the term found.

I can edit and sometimes join different codes but anything more than that is out of my league at the moment. I haven't had time to practice as much as I want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim c As Range, shtSrc As Worksheet, shtDest As Worksheet
    Dim arr, v, txt, destRow As Long

    arr = Array(3413, 3414, 3417) '<< array of values to look for

    Set shtSrc = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set shtDest = Sheets("Sheet2")
    destRow = 2 'start copying to here

    'ignore empty ranges
    For Each c In Application.Intersect(shtSrc.Range("J:J"), _
                                        shtSrc.UsedRange).Cells
        txt = c.Value
        For Each v In arr
            'does the cell contain the search number ?
            If txt Like "*" & v & "*" Then
                'copy to same row on sheet2
                c.EntireRow.Resize(2).Copy shtDest.Cells(c.Row, 1)

                '...or copy below previous hit
                'c.EntireRow.Resize(2).Copy shtDest.Cells(destRow, 1)
                'destRow = destRow + 2

                Exit For '<< stop checking this row
            End If
        Next v
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It was very close, all I needed to do was add an offset. The previous code I tried doing on my own crashed my excel, haha. Thank you so much.

Comment: For reference to those who might be looking for this in the future, that offset looks like this:
c.EntireRow.Offset(-1).Resize(2).Copy shtDest.Cells(destRow, 1)
                destRow = destRow + 2

Comment: Yes I forgot it was the row above you also wanted, not the one below...

Comment: @Tim Williams: Wow! I like that `Intersect` part! Saves me a lot of work, and is much easier to read (and maintain!) than what I usually do (did).